# Scale in printed map (mxd) is different in code to manual printing

Tags: arcobjects, printing, scale

*This question is related in part to a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/printing-mxd-at-a3-always-prints-at-b5) I have asked.*

I have tried printing an A3 mxd with the [Print Active View](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/025b5da7-9b10-4623-a51e-c038c348ce29.htm) code as published by ESRI and have changed only one line of code and that is, to change it to A3 size.

docPaper.FormID = 8;

This forces it to a size of A3 instead of the default 0 Letter size (esriPageFormLetter).

The map prints out fine(ish) but it is not to scale i.e. the map is supposed to be 1:10000, but the space between the graticule grids is 9.7cm, not 10cm as it should be.

If I print the EXACT same mxd out, but via the manual method i.e. in ArcMap itself, File -> Print. The scale is correct and it measures 10cm.

Important to note that I have not changed any of the Page and Print Setup settings between the two prints.

Why would it do this?

See pic below to help understand whats going on.

http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1959/scalemapcomparison.jpg

Comment: I would contact Esri Tech Support, this reads like a bug to me.

Comment: Sorry - I haven't updated this.  It has actually been submitted as a proper bug with ESRI - see NIM065953 (bug code on ESRI website) for details.

Comment: thanks for coming but with the NIM#. These are the kinds of things I like to keep track of.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments this problem seems to have been assigned an Esri Bug Number of NIM065953.

However, that bug number no longer appears on Esri Support's [Known Issues](http://support.esri.com/en/content/known-issues) page so it has presumably been resolved.

If anyone has additional information about the status of this bug, especially if it is found to still be present in the latest version of ArcGIS for Desktop, then feel free to edit it into this answer which I am making part of our Community Wiki, or to add your own Answer.